# Stacked bootstrap progress bars using Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Bootstrap 4 and earlier versions allow stacking multiple bars in a progress bar, as illustrated at https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/progress/ with code:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

However, ng-bootstrap seems to allow only one bar for NgbProgressbar as illustrated at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar with code:

```
<p><ngb-progressbar type="success" [value]="25"></ngb-progressbar></p>
```

I see some code at https://embed.plnkr.co/rx4RJUFjHqGYMA3jRxDL/ for stacked progress bars using Bootstrap 3 and a beta version of Angular 2, but it uses deprecated calls such as to CORE_DIRECTIVES and when I tried to run the code without that and in an Angular 4  / Bootstrap 4 environment the output was quite mangled.

Anyone know of a good way to get stacked progress bars in Angular 4 with Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I fixed it by wrapping the progress bars in `div` tags, and setting the width of those `div` tags and then setting the progress bars to 100%. Like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let player of Players" [ngStyle]="{width: (100/Players.length).toString() + '%'}" class="float-left">
    <ngb-progressbar type="success" [value]="100">{{100/Players.length}}</ngb-progressbar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need (pure angular progress-bar using flex-layout- style as you need)

```
    <div fxLayout="row" class="custom-progressbar">
                                      <div fxFlex="15" class="stat-bar bar-fail" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltip="fail"></div>
                                      <div fxFlex="30" class="stat-bar bar-pass" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltip="pass"></div>
                                      <div fxFlex="20" class="stat-bar bar-inprogress" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltip="inprogress"></div>
                                      <div fxFlex="30" class="stat-bar bar-expire" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltip="expire"></div>
                                      <div fxFlex="5" class="stat-bar bar-expiring" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltip="expiring"></div>
 </div>

//CSS
    .bar-fail {
    background: mat-color($mat-red, 500);
  }

  .bar-pass {
    background: mat-color($mat-green, 500);
  }

  .bar-inprogress {
    background: mat-color($mat-blue, 500);
  }

  .bar-expire {
    background: mat-color($mat-amber, 500);
  }

  .bar-expiring {
    background: mat-color($mat-orange, 500);
  }
.custom-progressbar {
  width: 206px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  background: mat-color($mat-grey, A100);
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid mat-color($mat-lgrey, 500);
  align-items: center;}
```